# Can anyone please suggest any Hindi POS Tagger appart from Tdil website's

Tags: java, nlp, pos-tagger

I have tried pos tagger provided by Tdil but results were not satisfactory also it created problem in incorporation with JAVA.

Comment: better to search on google,hindi bahut kam ko ati hai

Comment: tried it!!! but in vain even api is not working properly

Comment: kk i really dnt have any idea.Go ahead

Comment: would be helpful to describe what sort of problems you encountered

Comment: In the current form, this question will be closed on SO. Please provide details about what problems occurred when you tried to incorporate Tdil's POS tagger with Java.